# PyQt 5: How to maintain relative widget size when expanding a window

Tags: python, pyqt5, maya, pyside2

I'm working on a custom ui in Maya 2018 which uses PyQt5 (via PySide2 - there are some minimal differences, but it's essentially PyQt5).

I've got a `QHBoxLayout` with two widgets in it and their sizing policies are both set to 'expanding'.  I set the minimum width of one of them to be about twice as wide as the other.

Whenever I expand the window, the smaller widget expands until it's the same size as the larger one (which doesn't change size at all)... and *then* they both continue to expand at the same rate - both taking up half of the window.

I would prefer they maintain their sizes relative to each other throughout the whole expansion.

Is there a way to do this that I'm just completely overlooking?

Here's some simplified code I whipped up to reproduce the issue:

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as QtWidgets

class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(main_layout)
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        main_layout.setSpacing(5)

        w1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('small')
        w2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('large')
        w1.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        w2.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        w2.setMinimumWidth(250)

        main_layout.addWidget(w1)
        main_layout.addWidget(w2)

        self.setMinimumWidth(450)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)
        self.resize(450, 100)


test = TestDialog()
test.show()
```

Comment: could you post your codes?

Comment: Or you use PyQt5 or you use PySide2 since they are different packages. On the other hand it provides a [mre]

Comment: Indicate in the edition the question that PySide2 should use since Maya uses it natively, PyQt5 and PySide2 are different since the last one currently has a lot of bugs that could influence a possible solution.

Comment: Do you want the ratio between the widths of the widgets to be 1 to 2?

Comment: It's not necessarily 1 to 2, just somewhere around there (I'm currently experimenting with what the best size difference is going to be)... Do I need to figure out the exact mathematical ratio?

Comment: @silent_sight mmm, I don't understand. What exactly do you want? Did my answer work for you ?, please use `@username`

Comment: After playing around with setting the stretch, I found values of 4 and 5 worked out for me, and setting the minimum width would make the stretching still act funky.  To clarify my question on the comment, I was asking if I had to calculate the width of the other widget, then determine the actual ratio between the two...  I don't think 4 and 5 stretch values made the larger widget have a minimum of exactly 250 pixels, but it's not crucial it does...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the relationship between the widths to be maintained then you must set the stretch by adding the widgets:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        main_layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        main_layout.setSpacing(5)

        w1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("small")
        w2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("large")
        w1.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        w2.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )

        main_layout.addWidget(w1, stretch=1)
        main_layout.addWidget(w2, stretch=2)

        self.setMinimumSize(450, 100)
        self.resize(450, 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = TestDialog()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks!  Setting the stretch works great - I just had to play with those values to get it to have a ratio I liked...  I also found that if you're using this, you should not set a minimum width and just let the stretch take care of it.